# Make numbers 1 - 40 using digits 2, 0, 2, 1

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Using only the digits in the year 2021 and basic mathematical operations **(+, -, × and ÷)**, how many of the numbers from 1 to 40 can you make? Not all of the numbers are possible!

You **may** use each digit up to the number of times it appears in 2021, but not more. i.e., you can use 2 twice but the rest can be used once. You do not have to use every digit. The `-` operator may be used to make a negative (i.e. `-1`)

Also, you may concatenate (so you may make 12 by combining 1 and 2)

You don't need to use all the digits

Comment: Most answers you parentheses, but they are not mentioned in your post. Are they allowed?

Answer (score 9):

Given OP's deleted answer it looks like concatenation is allowed and not all numbers must be used. Here are the numbers I was able to do (26/40)

> $1 = 1$
>  $2 = 2$
>  $3 = 2 + 1$
>  $4 = 2 + 2$
>  $5 = 2 + 2 + 1$
>  $6 = (2+1) \times 2$
>  $7 = \frac{10}{2} + 2$
>  $8 = 10 - 2$
>  $9 = 10 - \frac{2}{2}$
>  $10 = 10$
>  $11 = 10 + \frac{2}{2}$
>  $12 = 12$
>  $14 = 10 + 2 + 2$
>  $16 = (10-2) \times 2$
>  $17 = 20 - 2 - 1$
>  $18 = 20 - 2$
>  $19 = 20 - 1$
>  $20 = 20$
>  $21 = 20 + 1$
>  $22 = 20 + 2$
>  $23 = 20 + 2 + 1$
>  $24 = 12 \times 2$
>  $32 = 20 + 12$
>  $38 = (20 - 1) \times 2$
>  $39 = (20 \times 2) - 1$
>  $40 = 20 \times 2$

Answer (score 5):

Assuming

> that "you can concatenate" means not only the individual digits, but also the results of their operations,

the available numbers are

> **0 to 12, 14 to 25, 28, 30, 32, 38, 39 and 40**.

because of

> the following Python script (*sorry for such an awkward one!*) which enumerate all possible binary trees with no more than 4 leaves and computes the result for expression denoted by each of the trees for all permutations of operators and operands (which are 2021 digits)
>
> ```
> from itertools import permutations, groupby
> from operator import itemgetter
>
> # all permutations of 2021 digits
> p = list(permutations([2, 0, 2, 1]))
> # all operations
> ops = [("+", lambda x, y: x + y), 
>        ("-", lambda x, y: x - y), 
>        ("*", lambda x, y: x * y),
>        ("/", lambda x, y: x / y if  y != 0 else 1000000),
>        ("|", lambda x, y: float(str(abs(int(x))) + str(abs(int(y)))))]
>
> # set of values
> v = set()
>
> for x in p:
>     # using 1 digit:
>     v.add((f"{x[0]}", x[0]))
>    # using 2 digits:
>     for (s1, op1) in ops:
>         v.add((f"{x[0]} {s1} {x[1]}", op1(x[0], x[1])))
>     # using 3 digits:
>     for (s1, op1) in ops:
>         for (s2, op2) in ops:
>             v.add((f"({x[0]} {s1} {x[1]}) {s2} {x[2]}", op2(op1(x[0], x[1]), x[2])))
>             v.add((f"{x[0]} {s1} ({x[1]}) {s2} {x[2]})", op1(x[0], op2(x[1], x[2]))))
>     # using 4 digits:
>     for (s1, op1) in ops:
>         for (s2, op2) in ops:
>             for (s3, op3) in ops:
>                 v.add((f"({x[0]} {s1} {x[1]}) {s2} ({x[2]} {s3} {x[3]})", op2(op1(x[0], x[1]), op3(x[2], x[3]))))
>                 v.add((f"(({x[0]} {s1} {x[1]}) {s2} {x[2]}) {s3} {x[3]}", op3(op2(op1(x[0], x[1]), x[2]), x[3])))
>                 v.add((f"(({x[0]} {s1} ({x[1]} {s2} {x[2]})) {s3} {x[3]}", op3(op1(x[0], op2(x[1], x[2])), x[3])))
>                 
>                 v.add(( f"{x[0]} {s1} (({x[1]} {s2} ({x[2]}) {s3} {x[3]})", op1(x[0], op3(op2(x[1], x[2]), x[3]))))
>
> results = list(r for r in v if 0 <= r[1] <= 40 and int(r[1]) == r[1])
> results.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
>
> abridged = [list(g)[0] for k, g in groupby(results, key=itemgetter(1))]
>
> for s in abridged: print(s)
> ```
>
> ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTJbtswEL3rK6bOZZgoiZacjPpLDB9oaKkQWRRI2pCQ9tvdGVFytLlNgfJAgpw3781CTN3aH6qKr9dMqxMUNtVWqdJAcaqVtlCn@nS20haqMj7kWp3rY@t1WEU2aZUeoOR7ylNLDJ73ALIsJ86gMoiCKISkyAtrvBp2UBbG4hiE@8iHwAfaw4MQPY0TYrunakN@e9w8bXwo5emYSGh8aLfQwBO0wgcP3MLN8xLyPIM8LiGPDPlEvC4Rr9BCkQHt33YQQFqaFMKgW2PPn3PPrFTSorEa5dFgUVlshBAU9vipFbwOXEGTWi7aRZbn1HgXypteUHheRjVvoKig3nZyD3A2RZVDX1v3eHmRSYKYbT6afXD4RcHwSTUde0R9N5wL86IJfSp4KJifqr0dEpoTwocJaWv2YUdOLsjvLMOtm@rE/6DjrBFbo6V1EgkuQxF0ibpL1McV4Sw2PqJbiH9MD1dIxSRb5mfMjXSa@Nt/TdwhYkbE64gvlgddKnSJO0s8pLVSLNJCRvND/JnhuuLfOiLGkhtHfr9FN8mvKvb9miiuS97r333JezHA7MtMYsCVtOcfyFVgFMSo0p5Ozbm0ZhiWuvsDmnt/4SEUwPcdaHLl8y0AWSXAY4SfBOycTQwsL4bmNL6n7e5zVmPIMvKoiyRPEx6unVAuKLpO7J3GPuv1sx97Lh@WPAc3mwzDB8Yt1JojMuJ6/Q0))

Note that all numbers not mentioned in hexomino's answer use concatenation of results (denoted here by $\#$):

> $15= ((1 + 2) \# 0) / 2$
>  $25 = 2 \# (10 / 2)$
>  $28 = (1 + 2) \# 0 - 2$
>  $30 = (1 + 2) \# 0$

Comment: I think that your interpretation of "concatenate" isn't the intended one - I rewrote that bit from "also you can make numbers from the digits such 12" which seems to say that you can only concatenate the initial digits.

Comment: @bobble At least, that makes hexomino's answer proven.

Answer (score 0):

> 1 =  2 + 0 - 2 + 1
> 2  = (2 + 0) / 2  + 1
> 3  =  2^2 - 1 - 0
> 4  =  2^2  - 0/1
> 5 =  2 + 0 + 2 + 1
> 6 =  (2 + 1)2  + 0
> 7  =  10/2 + 2
> 8  =  (2 + 1)! + 2   - 0
> 9 =  (2 + 1)^2  + 0/2
> 10  = (20/2)  / 1
> 11  = 20 / 2 + 1
> 12  =  12  + 0/2
> 13  =   12 + (0/2)!
> 14  =  12 + 2 + 0
> 15  =  C(10,2) / ( 2! + 0! )
> 16  =   2^ ( 0! + 1!  + 2!)
> 17 = 20 - 2 -1
> 18  =  20  - (2/1)!
> 19  = 20 - 2! + 1!
> 20 =   20 / (2 -1)
> 21  =  20 + 2  - 1
> 22  =  20 + 2/1
> 23  = 20 + 2 + 1
> 24  = ( 12) ( 2 + 0)
> 25 =   122  + 0!
> 26  =  20 + (1 + 2)!
> 27 = (2 ! + 0! ) ^( 2 + 1)
> 28 = C(10-2, 2)
> 29 = [(2+0!)! / .2] -1
> 30 = (2 + 0!)! * (1/.2)
> 31 = 2^(1/.2) - 0!
> 32 = 10  + 22
> 33 = 2^(1/.2) + 0!
> 34 = (2^2)! + 10
> 35 = [ (2 + 1) 1] ^2  - 0!
> 36 = [ (2 + 1)!  ] ^2  - 0
> 37 = 2! + 0!)! ^( 2)  +  1
> 38 = (20-1) * 2
> 39 =  20*2 - 1
>
> 40 = 10 (2 + 2)
>
> 41 =  20 * 2 + 1
>
> 42 = 21*2  - 0
> 43 = 21 *2  + 0!
> 44 = 22(1 + 0!)
> 45 = p(10, 2)/2
> 46 = 10.2(bar)/0.2(bar)
> 47 = C(10,2) + 2
> 48 = (10/.2)  -  2
> 49 =((2+1)! + 0!)^2
> 50 = 10^2/2
> 51 = 102/2
> 52 = (10/.2) + 2
> 53 = ( 12/.2 bar) - 0!
> 54 = ( 12/.2 bar) + 0
> 55 = (12 - 0!)/.2
> 56 = P(10-2,2)
> 57 =
> 58 =[ ( 2 + 0! )! / .1] -  2
> 59 = 12/.2  - 0!
> 60 = 20 ( 2 + 1)
> 61 = 12/.2  + 0!
> 62 = [( 2 + 0! )!/ .1] + 2
> 63 = 2^( [ 2 + 1]!)  - 0!
> 64 = 2^([2 + 1)! ] + 0
> 65 = C(12,2) - 0!
> 66 = C(12,2) - 0
> 67 = C(12,2)  + 0!
> 68 =
> 69 =
> 70 =
> 71 =
> 72 =  (12)  ( 2 + 0!)!
> 73 =
> 74 =
> 75 =
> 76 =
> 77 =
> 78 = C(12+0!, 2)
> 79 = [( 0! / .1 bar ) ^2] -2
> 80 = [2^( 2 + 0!)] / .1
> 81 =[( 2^0/.1 bar)^2]
> 82 =
> 83 = [ (0!/.1 bar)^2] +2
> 84 =
> 85 =
> 86 =
> 87 =
> 88 = P(10,2) - 2
> 89 = (20/.2 bar) - 1
> 90 = C(10,2) * 2
> 91 = ( 20/.2 bar) + 1
> 92 = P (10,2) +2
> 93 =
> 94 =
> 95 = (20 -1)/.2
> 96 =
> 97 =
> 98 = 10^2  - 2
> 99 = 20/.2 - 1
> 100 = 102  - 2

Comment: The question is only 1-40, you don't need to go all the way up to 100. Also, you should hide your answer in a spoiler tag `>!`, so as not to spoil the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves.

Comment: 25 does not fit

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the numbers using all the digits
I got 25 of them using all digits and 1 using only 3 digits

> $1 = \frac{2}{2} \times 1 + 0$
>  $2 = 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 0$
>  $3 = 2 + 1 + 2 \times 0$
>  $4 = 2 + 2 \times 1 + 0$
>  $5 = 2 + 2 + 1 + 0$
>  $6 = 2 \times (2+1) + 0$
>  $7 = \frac{10}{2} + 2$
>  $8 = 20 - 12$
>  $9 = 10 - \frac{2}{2}$
>  $10 = 12 - 2 - 0$
>  $11 = 10 + \frac{2}{2}$
>  $12 = 12 + 2 \times 0$
>  $13 = $
>  $14 = 10 + 2 + 2$
>  $15 = $
>  $16 = (10 - 2) \times 2$
>  $17 = 20 - 2 - 1$
>  $18 = 20 - 2\times 1$
>  $19 = 20 - 2 +1 $
>  $20 = 10 \times 2$   //missing a 2
>  $21 = 20 + 2 - 1 $
>  $22 = 22 - 0 \times 1 $
>  $23 = 20 + 2 + 1 $
>  $24 = 12 \times 2 + 0 $
>  $25 =  $
>  $26 =  $
>  $27 =  $
>  $28 =  $
>  $29 =  $
>  $30 =  $
>  $31 =  $
>  $32 = 22 + 10 $
>  $33 =  $
>  $34 =  $
>  $35 =  $
>  $36 =  $
>  $37 =  $
>  $38 =  (20 - 1) \times 2$
>  $39 =  20 \times 2 - 1$
>  $40 = (2+2) \times 10 $

Answer (score 0):

I see one solution for 13 in the above answers using factorials, but if exponentiation is allowed, we can also do:

> 13 = 12 + 2^0

The answer from MATIUS using factorials and C(n,r) function has a solution for 15 using C(n,r) but here is one with only factorial:

> 15 = 12 + 2 + 0!

Alternate solutions for 26 and 27 using factorials:

> 26 = 2*(12 + 0!)
>  26 = (2+2)! + 0! + 1
>  27 = 21 + (2+0!)!

Answer (score 0):

My try with all digits in order. (Used factorial and Exponents)

> 1 = (2 + 0 - 2) + 1

> 2 = ((2 + 0) ÷ 2) + 1

> 3 = (2 * 0) + 2 + 1

> 4 = (2 + 0 + 2) ÷ 1

> 5 = 2 + 0 + 2 + 1

> 6 = (2 + 0) * (2 + 1)

> 7 = (2 + 0!)! + (2 - 1)

> 8 = (2 + 0!)! + (2 ÷ 1)

> 9 = (2 + 0!)! + 2 + 1

> 10 = 20 ÷ (2 ÷ 1)

> 11 = (20 ÷ 2) + 1

> 12 = (2 + 0!)! * (2 ÷ 1)

> 13 = ((2 + 0!)! * 2) + 1

> 14 = 20 - (2 + 1)!

> 15 = ?

> 16 = 2 ˆ (0! + 2 + 1)

> 17 = 20 - 2 - 1

> 18 = (20 - 2) + 1

> 19 = 20 - (2 - 1)

> 20 = 20 ÷ (2 - 1)

> 21 = 20 + (2 - 1)

> 22 = 20 + (2 ÷ 1)

> 23 = 20 + 2 + 1

> 24 = (2 + 0 + (2 ÷ 1))!

> 25 = (2 + 0 + 2)! + 1

> 26 = 20 + (2 + 1)!

> 27 = (2 + 0!) ˆ (2 + 1)

> 28 = ?

> 29 = ?

> 30 = ?

> 31 = ?

> 32 = 2 ˆ ((- 0!) + (2 + 1)!)

> 33 = ?

> 34 = ?

> 35 = (((2 + 0!)!) ˆ 2) - 1

> 36 = (((2 + 0!)!) ˆ 2) * 1

> 37 = (((2 + 0!)!) ˆ 2) + 1

> 38 = ?

> 39 = (20 * 2) - 1

> 40 = (20 * 2) ÷ 1